# Change UIImageView from anotherVIewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sdk

I am trying change an `UIImageView` from other viewControllers, but I don't know why image does not change !! here is my code :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@class ViewController;
@interface CoverGallery : UIViewController {

    ViewController *mainViewController;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) ViewController *mainViewController;
- (IBAction)img1;
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)img1 {

    mainViewController.coverArt.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"coverDefault.png"];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

There is an `UIImageView` called **coverArt** in MainViewController , thanks

Here is my button action which switch between views :

ViewController (My First view)
.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
ViewController *mainViewController;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewController *mainViewController;


.m :

@synthesize mainViewController;


- (void) CoverGallery {

    CoverGallery *gallery = [[CoverGallery alloc] initWithNibName:@"CoverGallery" bundle:nil];
    gallery.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; 
    [self presentModalViewController:gallery animated:YES];

//here is the problem, compiler gives me the mainViewController is not the property of CoverGallery
gallery. mainViewController = self;
    [gallery release];

}
```

Comment: Have you checked if `[UIImage imageNamed:@"coverDefault.png"]` actually returns a valid image?

Comment: Where do you set your `mainViewController`?

Comment: yes set it as:[gallery.mainViewController = self]; Before you present the gallery view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you initializing the property mainViewController? You need set it as the MainViewController by setting its property when you present the modal view.
I imagine your doing this in the MasterViewController:

```
  CoverGallery *gallery = [[CoverGallery alloc]initWithNibName:@"CoverGallery" bundle:nil];
    gallery.masterViewContrller = self; //Set it here
    [self presentModalViewController:gallery animated:YES];
```

I fixed a typo..
and this:

```
ViewController *mainViewController;
```

should be:

```
MainViewController *mainViewController;
```

but you need to Import it in the same header file.

Comment: What is the name of the first ViewController? Is it named ViewController? I thought your first viewController was named MasterViewController, the one that is presenting the modal view.

Comment: did you do the @property (nonatomic, retain) Viewcontroller *mainViewController; in your header? and make sure to synthesize mainViewController in the .m.

Comment: It should be gallery.masterViewController = self. Not gallery.viewController = self.

Comment: Problem solved !! it was because of the name of my function and my class were same !!! I change it and solved :D thank you dear Hurbet